# Android - Xamarin Forms - Change Toolbar height in Xml

Tags: java, c#, android

how can i set the height of my android toolbar in XF ?

I added this but made no difference :

```
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

This is my Toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

I'm using Android 6.0 , AppCompat v7